# ioctl return -1 with errno set to EPERM

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I have a C program which calls *ioctl()* but it returns -1 and *errno* set to **EPERM**.
But I have changed mode of that file to "777".

Can you please tell me why *ioctl()* still returns -1 with *errno* set to **EPERM**?

Comment: Tell us what ioctl you're trying to call, with what parameters, and on what device. ioctl can do almost anything.

Comment: Are you the owner of the file...Try sudo chown yourname

Answer (score 0):

The device you are calling ioctl on may include some code that checks for capabilities before performing the action you requested.  Setting the permissions for the special file to 777 will not be sufficient in this case.  If you want to dig into the source for the driver that supports the device in question you can look for something like the following to figure out what capability is actually required.

```
if (! capable (CAP_SYS_ADMIN))
    return -EPERM;
```

You may want to read up on capabilities or just run your application as root as others have suggested.

[Linux Man Page for Capabilities](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities)

Answer (score -1):

Yea, EPERM (*Operation not permitted*) error indicate you don't have **sufficient permissions** to execute the operation.As **liw.fi** suggested,try executing with root privilege or tell us what is the operation to be done.